# SElinux domain transition for non-init process/files ( Android Natvie )

Tags: android, selinux, android-binder, seandroid

I'm writing Android Native programs and setting their SEPolicy

I want to know how to set the process context for **non-init program**, it seems that the domain transition doesn't work

I wrote 2 programs and put the built executable in **/vendor/bin**

One program, **my_service** is running as init daemon service;

While the other one, **my_client** is a non-init program, which has to be executed manually

These 2 programs use Binder IPC to communicate.

But I have trouble when trying to set the process context for **my_client**, which is a non-init program

---

For my_service, it's selinux context is set in mainly 2 files

1. my_service.te
2. file_context

```
# In file_context
/vendor/bin/my_service      u:object_r:my_service_exec:s0

# In my_service.te
type my_service, domain;
type my_service_exec, exec_type, file_type, vendor_file_type;

init_daemon_domain(my_service)
```

And I also use seclabel in **init.rc** files

```
# In init.rc
service my_service /vendor/bin/my_service
    class main
    console
    seclabel u:r:my_service:s0
```

I checked both file context and process context for **my_service**, and they're set as what I expected

---

For the SEPolicy of **my_client**, everything is similar to **my_service** except that it is not written in the **init.rc** file since it's not an init program

```
# In file_context
/vendor/bin/my_client      u:object_r:my_client_exec:s0

# In my_client.te
type my_client, domain;
type my_client_exec, exec_type, file_type, vendor_file_type;

init_daemon_domain(my_client)
```

For **my_client**, however, only file context is set to **my_client_exec**

I tried to run my_client and viewed the process context:

```
> # Executing my_client manually
> /vendor/bin/my_client 

> ps -AZ | grep my_client
> u:r:su:s0      root      5838  5514    5948   1688 0    0 R my_client
```

The process context is **su**, while I expected it to be **my_client**

Furthermore, I get information about **init_daemon_domain(XX)** in **te_macros**

I think that It will do domain transition: When init runs file with XX_exec context, it will transit its process context to XX!

So I change the rule to be :

```
# init_daemon_domain(my_client)
domain_auto_trans(su, my_client_exec, my_client);
```

But this violate some pre-defined policy.

---

By the way, the binder IPC between these 2 programs seems working.

What's confusing is that the following rules still works even the process context is not **my_client** ?

```
binder_call(my_client, my_service)
binder_call(my_service, my_service)
```

Is there any way to do domain transition for non-init program ?

Or I misunderstand anything about SEPolicy? Because all the resources I found are about setting SEPolicy for init program